# How to get the file size of a video for a selected time period in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, mobile-application, swift2

I have implemented a video range slider - https://github.com/itsmeichigo/ICGVideoTrimmer

In this video slider, I want to get video size every time the slider is changed for selecting the video range.

This delegate method is called everytime when I changes the slider.
I get the start time and end time for a video, but how can I get the file size for example - video's 10th sec to 40th sec ?

```
func trimmerView(trimmerView: ICGVideoTrimmerView, didChangeLeftPosition startTime: CGFloat, rightPosition endTime: CGFloat) {
    if startTime != self.startTime {
        //then it moved the left position, we should rearrange the bar
        self.seekVideoToPos(startTime)
    }
    self.startTime = startTime
    self.stopTime = endTime

    self.videoDurationLabel.text = "\(endTime - startTime) sec"

}
```

Comment: Do you have the total time of of the video?

Comment: yes, I can get it through  --- var duration = self.asset.duration --- but every time the slider changes, the total time of the video also chanegs. @shallowThought

Comment: My idea was to compute the from-to-time from the total time. There is most probably a more elegant way though.